Did Iran send 400 ballistic missiles to Russia?
Reuters still has this 'exclusive' story up from Feb 21, 2024:

Iran has provided Russia with a large number of powerful surface-to-surface ballistic missiles, six sources told Reuters, deepening the military cooperation between the two U.S.-sanctioned countries.
Iran's provision of around 400 missiles includes many from the Fateh-110 family of short-range ballistic weapons, such as the Zolfaghar, three Iranian sources said. This road-mobile missile is capable of striking targets at a distance of between 300 and 700 km (186 and 435 miles), experts say.
Iran's defence ministry and the Revolutionary Guards - an elite force that oversees Iran's ballistic missile programme - declined to comment. Russia's defence ministry did not immediately respond to a request for comment.
The shipments began in early January after a deal was finalised in meetings late last year between Iranian and Russian military and security officials that took place in Tehran and Moscow, one of the Iranian sources said.

But I'm skeptical because no Iranian ballistic missiles seem to have been fired at Ukraine, unlike North Korean ones. So, did Iran ship any ballistic missiles to Russia?
(I'm not asking about drones here. I know Iran sent some of those and now Russia makes their own Gerans.)

Helpful clarification about the Iranian drones AND the North Korean ballistic missiles! This is a good question for the site. It is quite a curious 'exclusive' from Reuters in February 2024. Six sources?! I look forward to any answers!

I'm not sure how you'd answer this factually. Iran denied the claims and reports in April suggested it was regarded as a possibility by the intelligence community (rather than having happened already). But it would be possible for Iran to deliver them in secret, even though it would be harder for Russia to use them without it being noticed.

@EllieKesselman: Interstingly VOA claims on Aug 9 that the delivery will happen soon https://www.voanews.com/a/iran-to-deliver-hundreds-of-ballistic-missiles-to-russia-soon-intel-sources-say/7736914.html So this story still has some legs.

Now WSJ it happened https://www.wsj.com/world/u-s-tells-allies-iran-has-sent-ballistic-missiles-to-russia-9558f4c4 "A U.S. official confirmed the missiles “have finally been delivered.”"

@EllieK: the strangest part is that Reuters now reports Russia received [the] missiles but no launchers for them https://www.reuters.com/world/middle-east/iran-withheld-launchers-missiles-sent-russia-sources-say-2024-09-21/

@Believeitornot... I need to go read that. The part about Russia receiving Iran's ballistic missiles but no launchers! I guess Iran has a lot of ballistic missiles because they fired many at Israel tonight. This map from The Telegraph... I have no words.

@Believeitornot... The ballistic missiles sent by Iran to Russia were Fath-360s which are short-rang: max 75 miles (121 km for the rest of the world) according to the 21 September Reuters article. That was excellent! Thank you for sharing. It is v thorough, not intentionally droll, but I lol'd at "Iran modifies trucks made by Mercedes and turns them into easily disguised missile launchers. X suggests Russia could modify its own military-grade vehicles. "A commercial, off-the-shelf Mercedes truck is just not that off-road capable."" Are Toyota trucks better? Also, what happened to sanctions?!

@EllieK: yeah, they sent to Russia stuff they could not (directly) use against Israel. Whether it's just for "safe keeping" like Saddam did with his air force once, who knows.
